# O que significa o - - no git checkout?

Tags: git

Quando usamos o `git checkout nomedoarquivo` qual a diferença com `git checkout -- nomedoarquivo`?

Não sei oque altera em usar esse `--`?

Answer (score 4):

O comando `git checkout "nome"` (sem `--`), funcionará do mesmo jeito que o `git checkout -- nome`(com `--`) quando não houver um **branch** com o mesmo nome que o **arquivo**.

Se existir um branch e arquivo com o mesmo nome no projeto, então o usuário tem que especificar em qual ele quer dar o checkout.

- `git checkout -- nome`  para escolher o **arquivo**
- `git checkout nome`  para escolher o **branch**

O `--` serve para evitar confusão. Indicando que o usuário está dando checkout em um arquivo e não em um branch com o mesmo nome.

O Git é inteligente o suficiente para tentar casar o comando caso não exista arquivos e branchs com nomes iguais. Por isso você não viu diferença no resultados dos comandos.

Na verdade, não é só com branchs que pode ocorrer ambiguidade. Como explicado no link da documentação em [desambiguação do git checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#_argument_disambiguation).

Comment: Entendi. Então basicamente o `--` serve para "pular" o campo branch. É como se a sintaxe completa do comando fosse: `git checkout branch arquivo`